# How to implement shopify api in android shopapp with kotlin?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, shopify

When trying to execute the code with kotlin for this application 
[shopapp-android](https://github.com/rubygarage/shopapp-android)
everything be fine, except when I implement shopify api according to instructions on github page as in code:

`val api = ShopifyApi(this, "BASE DOMAIN", "STOREFRONT ACCESS TOKEN", "API KEY", "API PASSWORD")`

An error is given from Android studio

`Program type already present: com.shopapp.gateway.BuildConfig`

note that application contains libraries

```
implementation project(':data')
implementation project(':domain')
implementation project(':gateway')
```

Is there a conflict between the library 'gateway' and ShopifyApi?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .. When implement Shopify Api by:

```
implementation'com.github.rubygarage:shopapp-shopify-android:1.0.4'
```

Which already implement gateway lib by:

```
implementation 'com.github.rubygarage:shopapp-android:1.0.5'
```

So I remove this implementation from project

```
implementation project(':gateway')
```

It work fine :)

Comment: I am still getting same error while building apk. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Are you by any chance adding a module (app or library) and using `com.shopapp.gateway` in the manifest? since the original github already has a module with that package name you won't be able to have a second one.